# Windows File Share Timespamps

Tags: windows, file-sharing, timestamp

Let's say Computer A creates a file in a folder hosted and shared by Computer B.

Using standard Windows file-sharing, will the 'created' timestamp for that file be set by Computer A's or Computer B's clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tested it with two Windows 7 machines, I've found that the computer actually writing the file to its disk is the one which sets the timestamp. (Computer B in this scenario).

I tested both created and modified timestamps and both were set by the host machine.