# File modification time on Windows file server

Tags: windows, server

Let's say there is a network consisting of several MS Windows clients and a MS Windows file server (exact OS versions are not known). Let's also say the clocks of all clients and the server are not synchronized and differ by some seconds or even minutes. Since I do not manage this network, I have to live with this situation.

When a client modifies a file on the server, which clock is used for the modification timestamp, the server's or the client's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows File Share Timespamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347025/windows-file-share-timespamps)